# Vent or Vent out

Tags: word-usage, usage

> She needed someone to **vent** her pent up emotions.
>
> She needed someone to **vent out** her pent up emotions.

What sounds better out of the two? Should"to" be included in the sentence? (Vent pent up emotions to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vent* without *out* is more idiomatic when the object is a person.

*Vent out* is used to refer to getting air into an enclosed place such as a room or possibly clothing to clear it of bad air or smells.

Comment: And should that "to" be included in the end?

Comment: Yes, include the *to* at the end.

Comment: So it should be "She needed someone to vent her pent up emotions to", right?